# How to allow a Next.js app to use Postgres via docker-compose?

Tags: node.js, docker-compose, prisma

## Problem

I'm trying to build a **minimal implementation of a Next.js app** that uses **Prisma** to communicate with a **Postgres** database, using **docker-compose** to run all services together.

I have a simple form to add a row to a simple table, but upon submission I see an **error that the app cannot communicate with the database.**

I've included what I've tried, the relevant code, and the full error below. If anyone has any insight as to what the error is or advice on how to go about this generally, that would be very appreciated. Thank you!

## What I've tried

1. There was no preexisting database before this project. I launched pgAdmin and created a table called `user` that reflects the structure as defined in the `prisma.schema` file. I populated it with an example (**side note:** how is this handled if you want to also create the database when the app is first launched?)
2. I've tried completely deleting the images from `docker-compose` and rebuilding from scratch

## Relevant code

### `prisma.schema`

My Prisma schema is as below:

```
datasource db {
  provider = "postgresql"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
  binaryTargets = ["native", "debian-openssl-1.1.x"]
}

model User {
  id    Int    @id @default(autoincrement())
  name  String
  email String @unique
}
```

### `.env`

```
POSTGRES_USER=myuser
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword
POSTGRES_DB=mydb
DB_PORT=5434
HOST_DB_PORT=5434

DATABASE_URL=postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@db:${HOST_DB_PORT}/${POSTGRES_DB}

APP_PORT=3000
HOST_APP_PORT=3000
```

### `docker-compose.yml`

```yaml
version: "3"
services:
  db:
    image: postgres
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: ${POSTGRES_USER}
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: ${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}
      POSTGRES_DB: ${POSTGRES_DB}
    ports:
      - "${HOST_DB_PORT}:${DB_PORT}"
    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      # - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
  api:
    build: .
    command: npm run dev
    environment:
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
      DATABASE_URL: ${DATABASE_URL}
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
    ports:
      - ${HOST_APP_PORT}:${APP_PORT}
    depends_on:
      - db
```

### `Dockerfile`

```
FROM node:16

WORKDIR .

COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

### `/src/pages/api/users.js`

This is the Next.js API endpoint that fails upon POST (and GET but I'm displaying example data at the moment)

```js
const { PrismaClient } = require('@prisma/client')
const prisma = new PrismaClient()

async function getUsers() {
  const users = await prisma.user.findMany()
  return users
}

async function addUser(user) {
  const createdUser = await prisma.user.create({
    data: user,
  })
  return createdUser
}

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'GET') {
    let users
    try {
      users = await getUsers()
      res.status(200).json(users)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      users = [
        { id: 1, name: "Alice", email: "alice@example.com" },
        { id: 2, name: "Bob", email: "bob@example.com" },
        { id: 3, name: "Charlie", email: "charlie@example.com" },
      ];
      //res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to get users' })
      res.status(200).json(users)
    }
  } else if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const user = await addUser(req.body)
      res.status(201).json(user)
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to create user' })
    }
  } else {
    res.status(405).json({ error: 'Method not allowed' })
  }
}
```

### `AddUserForm.js`

The React app that consumes this endpoint is a simple form with a button, added here for completeness

```js
import { useState } from 'react'

function AddUserForm() {
  const [name, setName] = useState('')
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('')

  async function handleSubmit(event) {
    event.preventDefault()

    const res = await fetch('/api/users', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify({ name, email }),
    })
    const data = await res.json()
    console.log(data)
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Add User</h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="name">Name:</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            id="name"
            value={name}
            onChange={(event) => setName(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="email">Email:</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            id="email"
            value={email}
            onChange={(event) => setEmail(event.target.value)}
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Add User</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default AddUserForm
```

## Error

I've included the relevant part of the error here

```
api_1  | PrismaClientInitializationError: 
api_1  | Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:
api_1  |
api_1  |
api_1  | Can't reach database server at `db`:`5434`
api_1  |
api_1  | Please make sure your database server is running at `db`:`5434`.
api_1  |     at fn.handleRequestError (/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:174:6750)
api_1  |     at fn.handleAndLogRequestError (/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:174:5907)
api_1  |     at /node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:3087
api_1  |     at async /node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:3294
api_1  |     at async t._executeRequest (/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:10748)
api_1  |     at async t._request (/node_modules/@prisma/client/runtime/library.js:177:10477)
api_1  |     at async addUser (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/users.js:36:25)
api_1  |     at async handler (webpack-internal:///(api)/./src/pages/api/users.js:71:26)
api_1  |     at async Object.apiResolver (/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils/node.js:372:9)
api_1  |     at async DevServer.runApi (/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:514:9)
api_1  |     at async Object.fn (/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:828:35)
api_1  |     at async Router.execute (/node_modules/next/dist/server/router.js:243:32)
api_1  |     at async DevServer.runImpl (/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:432:29)
api_1  |     at async DevServer.run (/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:831:20)
api_1  |     at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:375:20)
api_1  |     at async /node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:157:99 {
api_1  |   clientVersion: '4.12.0',
api_1  |   errorCode: undefined
api_1  | }
```

Comment: Could be the target port: Postgres listens on port by 5432 by default. You are mapping the host port to a different port than what Postgres normally listens on. Try mapping 5432:5432 and see if that works?